# How to calculate the color based on given fgColor indexed

Tags: openxml

I am working on Open XML,

```
<x:fill>
    <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
      <x:fgColor indexed="46" />
      <x:bgColor indexed="64" />
    </x:patternFill>
  </x:fill>
```

Above is a office 2007 document that converted from office 2003.
According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.foregroundcolor.aspx
Indexed attributes only used for backward compatibility purposes.

Above is my code, how to calculate the #Hex Color Code for indexed = 46?

Comment: isn't this just in styles.xml?

Comment: i think it is not, but is ok, i got the color indexes already.

Comment: I found it very difficult to find the website. So for those who come across this question here is the site where you can find the default mappings from indexed color value to ARGB value:
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.indexedcolors%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem, there is color indexes online. just search for it.

Answer (score 1):

I made this class for myself. Hope I save someone some trouble

```
public class IndexedColours
    {
        static Dictionary<string, string> Data;
        IndexedColours()
        {
            if(Data == null || Data.Count == 0)
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                Data.Add("0", "000000");
                Data.Add("1", "FFFFFF");
                Data.Add("2", "FF0000");
                Data.Add("3", "00FF00");
                Data.Add("4", "0000FF");
                Data.Add("5", "FFFF00");
                Data.Add("6", "FF00FF");
                Data.Add("7", "00FFFF");
                Data.Add("8", "000000");
                Data.Add("9", "FFFFFF");
                Data.Add("10", "FF0000");
                Data.Add("11", "00FF00");
                Data.Add("12", "0000FF");
                Data.Add("13", "FFFF00");
                Data.Add("14", "FF00FF");
                Data.Add("15", "00FFFF");
                Data.Add("16", "800000");
                Data.Add("17", "008000");
                Data.Add("18", "000080");
                Data.Add("19", "808000");
                Data.Add("20", "800080");
                Data.Add("21", "008080");
                Data.Add("22", "C0C0C0");
                Data.Add("23", "808080");
                Data.Add("24", "9999FF");
                Data.Add("25", "993366");
                Data.Add("26", "FFFFCC");
                Data.Add("27", "CCFFFF");
                Data.Add("28", "660066");
                Data.Add("29", "FF8080");
                Data.Add("30", "0066CC");
                Data.Add("31", "CCCCFF");
                Data.Add("32", "000080");
                Data.Add("33", "FF00FF");
                Data.Add("34", "FFFF00");
                Data.Add("35", "00FFFF");
                Data.Add("36", "800080");
                Data.Add("37", "800000");
                Data.Add("38", "008080");
                Data.Add("39", "0000FF");
                Data.Add("40", "00CCFF");
                Data.Add("41", "CCFFFF");
                Data.Add("42", "CCFFCC");
                Data.Add("43", "FFFF99");
                Data.Add("44", "99CCFF");
                Data.Add("45", "FF99CC");
                Data.Add("46", "CC99FF");
                Data.Add("47", "FFCC99");
                Data.Add("48", "3366FF");
                Data.Add("49", "33CCCC");
                Data.Add("50", "99CC00");
                Data.Add("51", "FFCC00");
                Data.Add("52", "FF9900");
                Data.Add("53", "FF6600");
                Data.Add("54", "666699");
                Data.Add("55", "969696");
                Data.Add("56", "003366");
                Data.Add("57", "339966");
                Data.Add("58", "003300");
                Data.Add("59", "333300");
                Data.Add("60", "993300");
                Data.Add("61", "993366");
                Data.Add("62", "333399");
                Data.Add("63", "333333");
            }
        }

        public static string GetIndexColour(string Index)
        {
            var d = new IndexedColours();
            var res = "";
            var exist = Data.TryGetValue(Index, out res);
            if (exist)
                return res;
            else return "000000";
        }
    }
```

Method to use the above code:

```
public static string GetCellColour(this Cell cell, SpreadsheetDocument d)
        {
            if (cell != null && cell.StyleIndex != null)
            {
                var valcell = cell;

                var styles = d.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart;
                var ss = styles.Stylesheet;
                var formats = ss.CellFormats;

                var cf = (CellFormat)formats.ElementAt((int)valcell.StyleIndex.Value);
                var fill = (Fill)styles.Stylesheet.Fills.ChildElements[(int)cf.FillId.Value];
                var fgc = fill.PatternFill.ForegroundColor;
                var cl = fgc == null || fgc.Rgb == null ? "FFFFFF" : fgc.Rgb.Value.Remove(0, 2);
                if (fgc != null && fgc.Indexed != null && fgc.Indexed.HasValue)
                {
                    cl = IndexedColours.GetIndexColour(fgc.Indexed.Value.ToString());
                }
                return cl;
            }
            else return "FFFFFF";
        }
```